# asmx web service and MVC 3 - How to use Model and map web service data to it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a web service and I want to display the data from web service in my MVC Razor View.

This is what I have done:

1) My Web Method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World... This is a Web Service consumed 
                                               through MVC Project";
    }
```

2) Added web reference to my MVC Project

3) View :

```
    <table><tr><td>

    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Get Message" 
                                       onclick="javascript:getMessage();" />

     </td></tr></table>

     <div id="Result"></div>
```

4) Script in my view

```
    function getMessage() {
    var URL = "/Home/getMessage/";
    $.get(URL, function (data) {
    $("#Result").html(data);

    });
   }
```

Note :  Controller name is Home and Action Method is getMessage

5) Action Method in Home

```
     public string getMessage()
     {
     Service1 mvcServiceProxy = new Service1();
     string message = mvcServiceProxy.HelloWorld();
     return message;

     }
```

I have followed the above steps and I am able to get the message in to my DIV as per my javascript code.

But If I have a model, and the property in my model is like:  public string Message{ get; set; }

How can I get the message into this property? DO I need to modify my action method and Javascript? Should I use something like JSON ?

I am not sure of how to achive this...

I just want to use my property and display the content (message) from my web service into my Razor view using my model property instead of passing the html value into DIV and directly displaying it.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance !!!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all property is basically used to read/modify any private data in a class from another Type.

So what you are trying to achieve shouldn't be done with properties.

The way you are trying is ok, also you can get a complete list of data in one call using Json and set it on html page according to your need.

So I would recommend playing around with Json.